# Y-Axis is reversed in camera perspective

Tags: camera, axis

I'm wondering how I can fix this problem.

When I move an object in camera perspective it moves the opposite direction.

I also reset user preferences to factory default with no success.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Couldn't recreate your problem. Upload your file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @Leander File added

Comment: Also, if I move the camera using `shift + F` then the cube will now move correctly.

Comment: Are you using Blam, or another camera calibration tool, which has put a setting on the camera not achievable through the UI? Maybe something like a negative focal length?

Comment: @RobinBetts I was using Blam but I disabled it and reset user preferences. Still had same results.